# CSS property : Sticky not working due to height property of HTML

Tags: html, css, sticky

I am trying to stick a div element HEADER to top but its not working because of height property of html tag.

```css
    body,html {
        height: 100%;
        font-family:'Montserrat',sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        color: #454545;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        line-height: 1.8em;
    }
    div.row1{
       width: 100%;
     }
    
     div.header{
       width: 100%;
       height: 100px;
       border-bottom: 2px solid black;
       position: sticky;
       position: -webkit-sticky;
       top: 50px;
       background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
     }
```

```html
    <div class="row1">
      <div class="header">
    
        <div class="navigation">
            <p>MENU LIST</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<div>
  <p>
orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</div>
```

Removing height property from html will stick the HEADER div. But, I need that height property for parallax effect above the Header div.
Can anyone tell me what should i do to stick Header div.

Thank You

Comment: php are not related to your problem here... Please give us the final HTML to works with..

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?

Comment: @APAD1:
Removing the height attribute of html will stick the header div to top. Else its not working.

Comment: move sticky to `div.row1` and removing height in your code won't make the element to be sticky

Comment: you must set `position:sticky` **and** `top:___` into `div.row1` and not on child

Answer (score -3):

Remove the width and height on the header, you want the header to occupy the space it needs not 100% of the space then it can be sticky.

Comment: height and width will not affect the problem